# Hole through the (rotating) earth problem - equations of motion in 2D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

**I have the following problem:**

Suppose to dig a straight tunnel that passes through the center of the earth. The tunnel does not coincide with the axis of rotation of the earth (so during the rotation the tunnel draws a cone). We know the diameter $d$ of the tunnel but it's irrelevant.

The objective is to find the equations of motion of a body that we let fall into this hole in the approximation that the rotation is very slow, therefore we can imagine the entrance of the hole moves in a straight line during the time of the experiment rather than an arch of circumference. For this reason we can set 2 Cartesian axes, one coinciding with the tunnel direction, the other one identified by the tangent velocity of the tunnel entrance at the moment in which the object is released. The object is released with vertical velocity $v=0$.

In this frame of reference the tunnel will move like in the figure

[image]

**This is how I tried to solve it:**

We know that the gravitational acceleration is given by $$\vec{g} = - \frac{GM}{r^2}\hat{r}$$ where we can always exclude the outer shell due to the shell theorem, therefore the mass we have to consider depends on $r$

$$M(r) = \rho \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$$

Putting all together we have that

$$\vec{g} = - \frac{GM(r)}{r^2}\hat{r} = -\frac{4 \pi G \rho r}{3}\hat{r} \equiv -Ar\hat{r} $$

Now I project the equation onto the two axes and I get

$$\begin{cases}
\ddot{x} = -A r sin\theta\\
\ddot{y} = -A r cos \theta
\end{cases}$$

where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\theta = tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{y})$.

The initial conditions are $$\begin{cases}
x(0) = 0\\
y(0) = R\\
\dot{x}(0) = v_{tan}\\
\dot{y}(0) = 0
\end{cases}$$

I have been trying to decouple the two equations but I can't seem to find a way.

**My question:**

Any idea on how to solve this problem?